# How to update a column for all rows after each time one row is processed by a UDF in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to update a column for all rows after each time one row is processed by a UDF.

The example has 3 rows with 6 columns. Column "A" has the same value across 3 rows; column "B" and "A" is the joint identifier of each row; column "C" is arrays with any letters in a,b,c,d,e; column "D" is the target array to be filled in; column "E" is some integers; column "abcde" is the integer array with 5 integers specifying the counts for each letter a,b,c,d,e.

Each row will be passed into a UDF to update the column "D" and column "abcde" according to the column "C" and column "E". The rule is: select the number, which specified by "E", of items from "C" to put into "D"; the selection is random; after each selection done for a row, the column 'abcde' will be updated **across all rows**.

For example, to process the first row, we randomly select one item from ('a','b','c') to put into "D". Let's say the system picked the 'c' in the column "C", so the value in "D" for this row becomes ['c'] and 'abcde' gets updated to [1,3,1,1,1] (before was [1,3,2,1,1]) for all three rows.

**Example data:**

```
#StandardSQL in BigQuery
#code to generate the example table
with sample as (
select 'y1' as A, 'x1' as B, ['a','b','c'] as C, [] as D, 1 as E, [1,3,2,1,1] as abcde union all
select 'y1','x2',['a','b'],[],2,[1,3,2,1,1] union all
select 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],[],3,[1,3,2,1,1])
select * from sample order by B
```

After the first row is processed:

```
with sample as (
select 'y1' as A, 'x1' as B, ['a','b','c'] as C, ['c'] as D, 1 as E, [1,3,1,1,1] as abcde union all
select 'y1','x2',['a','b'],[],2,[1,3,1,1,1] union all
select 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],[],3,[1,3,1,1,1])
select * from sample order by B
```

After the second row is processed:

```
with sample as (
    select 'y1' as A, 'x1' as B, ['a','b','c'] as C, ['c'] as D, 1 as E, [0,2,1,1,1] as abcde union all
    select 'y1','x2',['a','b'],['a','b'],2,[0,2,1,1,1] union all
    select 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],[],3,[0,2,1,1,1])
    select * from sample order by B
```

After the third row is processed:

```
with sample as (
    select 'y1' as A, 'x1' as B, ['a','b','c'] as C, ['c'] as D, 1 as E, [0,2,0,0,0] as abcde union all
    select 'y1','x2',['a','b'],['a','b'],2,[0,2,0,0,0] union all
    select 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],['c','d','e'],3,[0,2,0,0,0])
    select * from sample order by B
```

Don't worry about how the UDF will do the random selection. I'm just wondering, if it's possible in BigQuery to do the task to update the column 'abcde' in the way I want?

I've tried using UDFs, but I'm struggling to get it working because my understanding of a UDF is that it can only take one row in and produce multiple rows out. So, I can't update the other rows. Is it possible just using SQL?

**Expected output:**

After the first row is processed:

[image]

After the third row is processed:

[image]

**Additional information:**

```
create temporary function selection(A string, B string,  C ARRAY<STRING>, D ARRAY<STRING>, E INT64, abcde ARRAY<INT64>)
returns STRUCT< A stRING, B string, C array<string>, D array<string>, E int64, abcde array<int64>>
language js AS """
/*
for the row i in the data:
select the number i.E of items (randomly) from i.C where the numbers associated with the item in i.abcde is bigger than 0 (i.e. only the items with numbers in abcde bigger than 0 can be the cadidates for the random selection);
put the selected items in i.D and deduct the amount of selected items from the number for the corresponding item in the column 'abcde' FOR ALL ROWS;
proceed to the next row i+1 until every row is processed;
*/
return {A,B,C,D,E,abcde}
""";
with sample as (
select 'y1' as A, 'x1' as B, ['a','b','c'] as C, CAST([] AS ARRAY<STRING>) as D, 1 as E, [1,3,2,1,1] as abcde union all
select 'y1','x2',['a','b'],[],2,[1,3,2,1,1] union all
select 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],[],2,[1,3,2,1,1])
select selection(A,B,C,D,E,abcde) from sample order by B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#StandardSQL
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 'y1' AS A, 'x1' AS B, ['a','b','c'] AS C, ['c'] AS D, 1 AS E, [1,3,2,1,1] AS abcde UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y1','x2',['a','b'],['a','b'],2,[1,3,2,1,1] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y1','x3',['c','d','e'],['c','d','e'],3,[1,3,2,1,1] UNION ALL

  SELECT 'y2' AS A, 'x1' AS B, ['a','b','c'] AS C, ['a','b'] AS D, 2 AS E, [1,3,2,1,1] AS abcde UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y2','x2',['a','b'],['b'],1,[1,3,2,1,1] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y2','x3',['c','d','e'],['d','e'],2,[1,3,2,1,1]  
),
counts AS (
  SELECT A AS AA, dd, COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM sample, UNNEST(D) AS dd
  GROUP BY AA, dd
),
processed AS (
  SELECT A, B, ARRAY_AGG(aa - IFNULL(cnt, 0) ORDER BY pos) AS abcde
  FROM sample, UNNEST(abcde) AS aa WITH OFFSET AS pos
  LEFT JOIN counts ON A = counts.AA 
  AND CASE dd 
        WHEN 'a' THEN 0 
        WHEN 'b' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'c' THEN 2 
        WHEN 'd' THEN 3 
        WHEN 'e' THEN 4 
      END = pos
  GROUP BY A, B
)
SELECT s.A, s.B, s.C, s.D, s.E, p.abcde
FROM sample AS s
JOIN processed AS p
USING (A, B)
-- ORDER BY A, B
```

> Don't worry about how the UDF will do the random selection

*So, as you can see - I just put "random" values into sample data to mimic D*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I probably didn't make it clear about the issue I have. I put some extra information in the post. Basically I want to use UDF to do this random selection step I mentioned. I explained how the algorithm in the UDF is supposed to work in the additional information (between /* */). The main problem is I need to update this column 'abcde' for ALL ROWS after each time one row is processed in the UDF(consider each row is dealt with one after another ...if possible..). Sorry about any confusions I made... Many thanks again!! :)

Comment: @Ran - 1) I think you were clear enough and  you said not to worry of that step in udf so that is why i skipped this step and pre-filled field D (I even quoted that in the bottom of my answer)  2) when you say `ALL ROWS` - I got it  - but I thought of all rows for same A field (otherwise field A makes no much sense) - but please confirm it is actually for ALL fields 3) above solution does what you want in a set manner - the way how SQL usually works - not in a row by row (cursor) way - which is not suitable  for big data 4) clarify #2 and I will update my answer :o)

Comment: about #2, you understand it correctly that it is indeed all rows for a same A field. Your SQL is working on the right level of aggregation (many thanks again! ^_^) ; and about #3, I understand that this algorithm is indeed not suitable for big data and usually SQL won't work for this sort of algorithm. But I was hoping that there'll be some 'unusual' ways to make it happen in BigQuery? ... Again really appreciate your help!! :)

Comment: Sure.If for some reason you really really need to do it in cursor manner  - technically it is possible to pass to udf all rows with the same A key to js udf and do row by row inside - but it is not efficient and can lead to quite big billing tier!! if you still interested in this type of solution  - let me know  - i can post another answer for this (will take some little time though :)

Comment: I am interested! Whenever you have time!! And a thousand times of thanks!!! ^_^ ^_^